# Generic type function (property)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return a T type value.

```
public T this[int index]
{
     get
     {
           if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
              return (T) dynEx[index].Int;
           else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
              return (T) dynEx[index].Str;
     }
}
```

dynEx is a complex object that returns an object based on some custom expression.

The code above obviously doesn't work because it has an error: "cannot convert type 'int' to T" and "cannot convert type 'string' to T".

How can I achieve this without having a performance impact?

This property is called more than a thousand times per frame (it's a game).

Comment: How is `T` related to the enclosing type?

Comment: If you only care about 2 types I think a strategy that uses overloads would make more sense than generics.

Answer (score 3):

In order to cast to `int`, you'll need to cast the result to `object` first, potentially boxing. It's annoying, but unfortunately it's a limitation of C# generics - for good reasons that escape me right now, unfortunately. So you want:

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            return (T) (object) dynEx[index].Int;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return (T) (object) dynEx[index].Str;
        }
        // TODO: Whatever you want to happen if T isn't int/string
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because `T ` can be a value or reference type, so at compile time would be potentially dangerous cast? It's my speculation.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I think it's partly along the lines of whether there can be user-defined conversions, but I'm not going to speculate too much without checking :)

Comment: To be honest, it's not "unfortunately" a limitation of C# generics, it is unfortunately a limitation of someone writing a too generic non-generic type. It's basically an abuse of the whole idea of generics and I'm not sure why the C# compiler guys should make this easy to write.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the limitation is needing the intermediate cast, that is distinct from the validity of the pattern itself.

Comment: I realize that, I know full and well why the compiler refuses to do what you want it to do, but in reality you have a generic type that is revolving around some type `T`, but internally you have all sorts of types and you're now struggling to comprehend how to convert from "any type" to *a specific type `T`* and frankly, this is not a compiler problem. It's a design problem

Comment: Have you considered just using `Convert.ChangeType`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree. A large chunk of sample code is required to determine if the use makes any since or not.

Comment: To be honest, in my opinion it doesn't make sense at all. But that's just it, it's my *opionion*. However, to make a generic type that uses a `T` without being able to handle **any** `T` is a design flaw. In my mind it means that some other tool should've been used.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `Convert.ChangeType` takes an object parameter and returns an object, so I don't see how it would prevent the boxing scenario.

Comment: It wouldn't, but the whole premise is flawed. The class is supposed to take **any `T`**, and yet we're dealing with details such as how to get from one type to another.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: There are times when you can write a generic method which *can* handle any `T`, but is optimized for specific types of `T` - I've certainly run into that before, and been annoyed by this.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that angle of the problem, I have classes at work that has the same problem. I just can see a solution to it that would solve all problems.

Comment: Wow, this blew up.

T can be either int, float, double, string, or bool. The Generic T is determined at compile time, though. Would boxing affect performance?

I think it's silly to box it to object to cast back to int... since dynEx[index].Int returns an int value.

Comment: completely agree with @LasseV.Karlsen. if the caller knows they want an `int`, why not just call the `.Int` property of the contained class on their end? why does the container need to do this additional work? (genuine questions, not judgements...interested in what the use case is here)

Comment: JSON data types are converted into objects, but some data (string) are mathematical expressions with some function calls ( e.g. "enemyIncDmg *= ArmorReduction * Player.Gears.Modifiers(thisEvent)" ). My custom parser can read this expression and mark them as a dynamic value (dynEx). Each JSON entry is stored in a class called DynamicEx, the class in the original post.

So a player would have bunch of values parsed from JSON, where some of them are "dynamic" that are determined later in the game, hence the use of value.